# FileNotFoundError: pandas python 3.6

Tags: csv, pandas, filenotfoundexception, python-3.6

I'm trying to import a `.csv` file utilizing pandas library in python 3.6. With the simple `data = pd.read_csv('./Data.csv')` I get the following error... `FileNotFoundError: File b'./Data.csv' does not exist`. I also tried `import os` and then... `data_path = os.path.abspath('./Data.csv')` and then `data = pd.read_csv(data_path)` but got the same error. I'm utilizing vs code, python 3.6, and all my libraries are updated.

Comment: How do you run your script? Are you sure working directory really contains that file?

Comment: Yes it does contain the file. The code it's in a `.py` file and I'm utilizing vs code to run each "cell" with the `#%%` prefix.

Comment: Not sure what your mean by "I'm utilizing vs code to run each "cell" with the #%% prefix". You are using jupyter, right?

Comment: No. vs code is the cross platform, free edition Visual Studio Code editor. VS Code has an extension where you can run python code as "cells" as you do in Jupyter-Notebook or Jupyter-Lab. The difference here is that I'm not creating a Jupyter file but a `.py` file that I can use in a production application right away.

Comment: I would suggest to try to run a .py file (or part of it, that is reading the .csv) from terminal at the dir where both .py and .csv are located and see what will happen.

Comment: RuntimeError: Python is not installed as a framework. What the heck does that means? I develop apps in Django, write other python scripts in the same editor that I'm writing this very script. Lol

Answer (score 0):

You can try put the absolute route of the file, like this by example:

```
df = pd.read_csv('/home/$USER/Desktop/Data.csv')
```